# Make App Engine for PHP load BCMath or php.ini

Tags: php, google-app-engine, archlinux

I'm running the latest php-cgi from Arch Linux's repos. I enabled the BCMath module on php.ini and it works when I run php, php-cgi and php in Apache. However, when dev_appserver.py runs php, somehow it loses the configuration I set in php.ini. Causing both BCMath, soap and my locale settings to not load, causing:

```
dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path /usr/bin/php-cgi appengine-try-php
PHPEnvironmentError: The PHP runtime requires the "bccomp" function, which is not defined.
```

`php-cgi -i | grep -i bcmath` returns BCMATH enabled.

`php -i | grep -i bcmath` returns BCMATH enabled.

`php -r "echo bccomp('1.0001', '1', 5);"` returns 1.

Is there any way to make dev_appserver.py load the module or php.ini?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php/runtime.py

Supports loading a php.ini file from the project directory, as such you can just drop a php.ini file in the project directory. It will by default ignore the php.ini file in /etc/php/php.ini unlike all other instances of php. Here is the php.ini script I'm using. It likely has extra modules and modules that are missing compared to the production App Engine.

```
date.timezone = America/New_York
extension=bcmath.so
extension=bz2.so
extension=curl.so
extension=gd.so
extension=gettext.so
extension=mcrypt.so
extension=mysqli.so
extension=mysql.so
extension=openssl.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
extension=soap.so
extension=zip.so
```

Happy Apping.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code that fails - we check if the function exists.

```
if (!function_exists('bccomp')) {
  echo "The PHP runtime requires the \"bccomp\" function, which is not ";
  echo "defined.\n";
  echo "If you built PHP using \"configure\" then please rebuild with:\n";
  echo ' ./configure  --enable-bcmath';
  exit(1);
}
```

I don't know why you'd have the extension enabled but the function not existing. Probably try listing the functions that are available to double check it's there.

```
 php -r 'print_r(get_defined_functions());' | grep -i bccomp
```

Comment: It seems the devappserver.py script completely ignores php.ini. I have my timezone settings declared there and the bcmath module specified there. Causing devappserver to load a php without the proper settings.

running php and php-cgi from the commandline loads the php.ini file. But when I venture to modify check_environment.php and inject a phpinfo(), it gives a php that is completely ignorant of php.ini, including not having the timezone set.

Comment: I have updated the problem... its as if dev_appserver.py ran php-cgi with -n, "No php.ini file will be used". and Yes, bccomp is function 938 when I ran `php -r 'print_r(get_defined_functions());' | grep -i bccomp`

Comment: Turns out dev_appserver.py loads its own php.ini, on line 145 of runtime.py. I'm looking into it.

Comment: Turns out, you can drop a php.ini in the project directory and it will be read. Unfortunately now I get a weird error about "No input file specified."